# High Current Buck Converter with wide input voltage

Tags: batteries, buck, converter, high-current, power-delivery

I'm currently building a powerbank with PD outputs that are capable of outputting **5 amps** at **20 volts**, but my battery pack is **33.6V (8S Li-ion)**. I've managed to find a possible **buck converter IC** **(XR76208EL-F)**, but it seems to me that it won't handle that much current at **20 volts**. Also space is limited so I insist on using smd components. Could anyone suggest me a suitable buck converter IC for my requirements? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, also note that product recommendations are off-topic here since they are very dated and aren't very helpful to others. What, in the datasheet, makes you think your IC cannot handle 20V@5A output?

Comment: The datasheet provides an example application diagram which shows it can output 8 amps at 3.3VDC which is 26.4W and it is far from 100W. But other than that this is my only concern.

Comment: That's just an example application schematic. Buck converter power levels don't work the way you think they work. If a buck converter can output 8A, it pretty much do that anywhere in its operating voltage range. The operating voltage range (and maximum stepdown ratio) somewhat independent of that.

Comment: I see. Then I misunderstood it, could you write it as an answer so then I can mark it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Besides, it's easier for a buck converter to step down smaller ratio than a larger ratio, and your ratio of 33.6V to 20V is much smaller than the application schemati'c 24V to 3.3V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The datasheet provides an example application diagram which shows it can output 8 amps at 3.3VDC which is 26.4W and it is far from 100W. But other than that this is my only concern.

Buck converter power levels don't work the way you think they work. If a buck converter can output 8A, it pretty much do that anywhere in its operating voltage range. The operating voltage range (and maximum stepdown ratio) are somewhat independent of that.

Besides, it's easier for a buck converter to step down smaller ratio than a larger ratio, and your ratio of 33.6V to 20V is much smaller than the application schematic's 24V to 3.3V.